# python for with while inside

Tags: python, loops

> Your program should read a sequence of L integers, where each integer
>   is N, separated by a whitespace. N is in range [0, 99]. L is in range
>   [1, 400]. Test sample
>
> input 40 40 40 40 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 17 17 92 92 92 92 92 86 86
>   86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86
>
> output 4 40 8 29 2 17 5 92 10 86

```
line = input('Please enter the sequence: ').split()

list = []

for value in line:

    print('\nvalue -', value)

    count = 0

    while value in line:
        if value == '17':
            print('found')

        if line[0] == '17':
            print('is here')

        del line[0]
        count += 1
        print('\ninside value -', value, ' count - ', count)
        print('\n', line)

    list.extend([count, value])
print('\n', list)
```

This is a simple problem but pay attention at number 17, if the sequence is 2 or fewer numbers, it is not counted, if it has at least 3 numbers, it is normally counted. Can someone please explain what the problem is? I've checked several times and could not understand. I've already found a better solution, but I still would like to know what is the problem in the above Python code. Thanks!

Comment: Don't modify the list in-place by deleting stuff from it.

Comment: You will want to get acquainted with a debugger, which will allow you to step through the code, one line at a time, inspecting the value of all the variables at each step. Plenty of options are available with a good free one being the debugger included with PyCharm Community Edition.

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Thanks, but I've already analyzed and debugged the code, and I don't understand why the 'for' loop gets the number 92, when the line[0] is 17, and why it works if the internal sequence is greater than 2. Even in the debug, I see no sense in what happened.
I decided to add it here because maybe this is a special way 'while' loops work inside 'for' loops in Python, and I may not know/understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without using any libraries, this can be done with (step-by-step process):

```
_input = "40 40 40 40 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 29 17 17 92 92 92 92 92 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86 86"

# transforming the raw values into a list/array
number_array = [int(i) for i in _input.split(' ')]

# returns unique values from input
number_unique = []
for na in number_array:
    if na not in number_unique:
        number_unique.append(na)
    pass

# counts how many times the values appeared on the list, respectively
number_count = []
for n in number_unique:
    number_count.append(number_array.count(n))

# pairing of the count and the unique value
res = []
for nc, nu in zip(number_count, number_unique):
    res.append("{} {}".format(nc, nu))

print(' '.join(res))
# 4 40 8 29 2 17 5 92 10 86
# concatenating using join
```

Comment: Although the question text doesn't make it all that clear, the real question they are asking is *not* about how to solve the quoted problem. The question is why they are encountering the unexpected result with their code.

Comment: He might use this as a reference, if ever he will.